# VBA application.match error 2015

Tags: vba, excel

In my `Main` procedure I want to write a quick if-statement which checks whether the user has made a valid input (user chooses number of project from list of data, see attached screenshot). For that I am checking whether the project number is not part of the list of projects. If that is true, an error message is displayed; if not then a number of other procedures are called.

For some reason though I get error 2015 when I run it, which means that the if-statement is always true, even on correct user entries. Can someone help me understand the error please?

- The project number input is a named cell called "IdSelect" and is on a sheet called "Invoice"
- The data against which this input is checked is on a sheet called "Input"
- The data is stored in column B and called "ProjectList"

Code below (note: I have tried pasting it 5 times but the formatting still won't work this time for some reason - any idea what that could be? The code is properly formatted. Sorry for the messy display; if anyone can tell me what that problem might I would be very grateful!)

```
Sub Main()
    'Turn off screen updating
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    'Define variable for currently active cell to reactivate it afterwards
    Dim OldActiveSheet As Object
    Dim OldActiveCell As Object
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim ProjectList As Range
    Set OldActiveSheet = ActiveSheet
    Set OldActiveCell = ActiveCell
    'If-statement to check whether project number is valid or not
    Worksheets("Invoice").Activate
    'Print to Immediate Window to check value - remove later
    Debug.Print Range("IdSelect").Value
    If IsError(Application.Match(Range("IdSelect").Value, "ProjectList", 0)) Then
        'Print to Immediate Window to check value - remove later
        Debug.Print Application.Match(Range("IdSelect").Value, Worksheets("Input").Range("ProjectList"), 0)
        MsgBox "Invalid Choice: Project with this number does not exist!"
        Exit Sub
    Else
        'Call procedures to execute
        Call SortData
        Call Count_Line_Items
        Call Count_Total_Rows
        Call Write_Services(ServCnt)
        Call Write_Expenses(ExpCnt)
    End If
    'Reactivate previous active cell
    OldActiveSheet.Activate
    OldActiveCell.Activate
End Sub
```

Screenshot from "Input" sheet:

[image]

Comment: Can you please format the `subroutine` :-) ? You had put `code` wrongly. You need to use `square brackets` in the question editor.

Comment: Ok thanks, that explains it! :-) Thanks for editing!

Comment: Please try out the answer. Comment if you require further clarification or accept if it solved the issue ;-)

Comment: [is this just useful or brilliant](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/148066/can-i-search-my-comments-using-some-keywords)? In a quest of getting a great feature :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The way you refer to range is rather odd.. because you missed out `range` reference. Oddly enoughbthat you do it correct on the next line at 
`Debug.Print Application.Match(Range("IdSelect").Value, Worksheets("Input").Range("ProjectList"), 0)`

So try this please: (it take me 100 years to format my own post on mobile.....). Make sure to use **explicit reference** as shown in my sample code below. Set your sheets accordingly.

```
Dim ws as Worksheet
Set ws = Sheets(1)

 IsError(Application.Match(ws.Range("IdSelect").Value, ws.Range("ProjectList"), 0)) Then
```

And here is for you to read on for [error handling on on `match`.](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/615916-catching-error-visual-basic-applications-match-function.html)

Comment: Thank you very much (and extra bonus for doing it on your mobile! :-) ). It works perfectly fine now and I will take the lesson about explicit referencing on board for the future. Thank you as well for the link!