# Search for exact match of string in excel row using VBA Macro

Tags: vba, excel

How do I search for a string in one particular row in excel? the I have the row index in a long type variable.

```
Dim rowIndex As Long
rowIndex = // some value being set here using some code.
```

Now I need to check if a particular value exists in the row, whoose index is rowIndex.

If there is match, I need to get the column Index of the first matching cell.

I have tried using Match function, but I dont know how to pass the rowIndex variable in place of the cell range.

```
Dim colIndex As Long    
colIndex = Application.Match(colName, Range("B <my rowIndex here>: Z <my rowIndex here>"), 0)
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try this:

```
Sub GetColumns()

Dim lnRow As Long, lnCol As Long

lnRow = 3 'For testing

lnCol = Sheet1.Cells(lnRow, 1).EntireRow.Find(What:="sds", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False).Column

End Sub
```

Probably best not to use colIndex and rowIndex as variable names as they are already mentioned in the Excel Object Library.

Comment: I heard using Find is generally slower than Match. I'm looking for a match example though.

Comment: You need to replace `xlPart` by `xlWhole` to be able to find the exact match

Comment: Works great. Thanks.

Comment: Works fine when the text is in "lnRow", however I get Run time error 91, when searching through rows that may or may not contain the data.

Comment: Causes quite a lot of trouble if you don't know whether something is in the row or not.

Answer (score 1):

This is not another code as you have already helped yourself; but for you to take a look at the **performance** when using Excel functions in VBA.

- [`Match()` is faster for smaller number of search, but it isn't when it compared to a large number of data. And in that instance you may consider a `variant array/dictionary/arrayList` approach depending on if you want to sort, you want to have duplicates or not..](http://fastexcel.wordpress.com/2011/10/26/match-vs-find-vs-variant-array-vba-performance-shootout/)
- [Error handling on Match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14188010/vba-application-match-error-2015)

PS: 
**On a latter note, if you wish to do `pattern matching` then you may consider `ScriptingObject **Regex`.

Answer (score 0):

Use worksheet.find (worksheet is your worksheet) and use the row-range for its range-object.
You can get the rangeobject like: worksheet.rows(rowIndex) as example

Then give find the required parameters it should find it for you fine.
If I recall correctly, find returns the first match per default.
I have no Excel at hand, so you have to look up find for yourself, sorry

I would advise against using a for-loop it is more fragile and ages slower than find.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, I found the answer.

This will do the trick.

```
Dim colIndex As Long    
colIndex = Application.Match(colName, Range(Cells(rowIndex, 1), Cells(rowIndex, 100)), 0)
```