# VBA: Setting a range object using Sheets("sheet name").Rows(1).Find

Tags: vba, excel

I have a set of code that looks something like this, where I am searching row 1 for a specific word and want to return the column number where it is found:

```
Dim MyRng As Range
Dim MySht As Worksheet
Set MySht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Numbers")
Set MyRng = MySht.Rows(1).Find("Header 3" etc...)
FindSeriesColumn = MyRng.Column
```

It seems logical that I should be able to eliminate the need for defining a worksheet object and should be able to do the following:

```
Dim MyRng As Range  
Set MyRng = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Numbers").Rows(1).Find("Header 3" etc...)
FindSeriesColumn = MyRng.Column
```

However, the `Set MyRng ...` line results in an error. What is improper about using `ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet Name").Rows(1).Find...`?

Comment: you can... https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839746.aspx I do it often. Unless I'm misunderstanding the problem. Are you sure the problem is not with the .rows(1) part? For example I just tested the following line in the immediate window of the project I'm working on: ?f_overview.cells.Find("Projet C").Address and it answered correctly with $C$3.

Comment: What error are you getting?  That always helps.

Comment: I think you want entirerow.. See here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14212967/search-for-exact-match-of-string-in-excel-row-using-vba-macro

Comment: That code (second block) runs fine on my machine (Excel 2013).  What is `FindSeriesColumn` defined as in your `Dim` statement, or is it not?  Also, what error do you get on that line?

Comment: I believe the problem may be in the part you omitted; specifically the `, After:=<some cell>` parameter. You should be able to delete that parameter.

Comment: I am getting run-time error '424', "object required". @Jeeped it may be that that part is affecting it, but why then does it work in the first code block and not the second?

Comment: Sorry @teepee - I couldn't say without a very close examination of the workbook. The code works for me in both forms with teh parameters I've used to 'fill in the blanks'.

Answer (score 0):

Use this form:

```
Sub fhksadf()
  Dim MyRng As Range
  Set MyRng = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Numbers").Rows(1).Find(what:="Header 3")
  FindSeriesColumn = MyRng.Column
  MsgBox FindSeriesColumn
End Sub
```

[image]

**EDIT#1:**

It is easier to define the range being examined, and start the **Find()** after the beginning of that range:

```
Sub fhksadf()
  Dim MyRng As Range
  Dim temp As Range
  Set temp = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Numbers").Rows(1).Cells
  Set MyRng = temp.Find(what:="Header 3", After:=temp(1))
  FindSeriesColumn = MyRng.Column
  MsgBox FindSeriesColumn
End Sub
```

Comment: This form still gives me some trouble. I actually have it set up like so, and it too works only when I define the sheet object separately, but not when it's all done at once:

Comment: `Set SeriesRng = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ShtName).Rows(SeriesTitleRow).Find(what:=SeriesName, After:=Sht.Cells(SeriesTitleRow, 1), lookin:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=True)`

Comment: which I now see the problem in because of the "after" statement, so that's solved. Sorry everyone. Which raises a related question: what would be the quickest way of searching across a given row in this case? I.e. am I employing too many unnecessary  constraints to the "find" function?

Comment: @teepee  remember that **Find() depends on the previous usage of Find()**.  Always start after the *beginning* of the range.