# Clculate MEDIAN NA DIV/0

Tags: excel, excel-formula

The problem is I'm trying to use a build-in function MEDIAN() on a column to calculate median, whereas the cells contain #N/A and #DIV/0!. 
I have tried to use IF statement such as `=IF(ISERROR(J:J), "", MEDIAN(J:J))` but it did not work.

Similarly, when am calculating average, I found a perfect way which is `AVERAGEIF(J:J,"<>#DIV/0!")` to calculate mean.

Such that I am looking for a similar function to solve this problem, as I don't want to use a loop, my data set is huge.

Any help would be much appreciated!!

Thanks!

---

UPDATE:
`ActiveSheet.Evaluate("GEOMEAN(IFERROR(IF($J:$J <> """",$J:$J), """"))")` the solution worked great, thanks guys! But what if I also want to void negatives and zeros in the formula?

Comment: I use VBA/Excel to do this

Comment: I dont quite understand what you mean, the code I included is in VBA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
=MEDIAN(IFERROR(IF($J:$J <> "",$J:$J), ""))
```

Confirm with CTRL+ALT+ENTER and it should return the proper median.

Comment: From what I understood from the question he was not looking for a VBA answer, rather an 'excel code' answer. Perhaps just an error in communication?

Comment: Hi guys, sorry for the miscommunication. I defenitely meant a script in VBA not a Excel fomula. But thanks anyway!

Comment: I think `yourSheetVariable.Evaluate([formula here])` will work fine: seems to handle array formulas with not problem.

Comment: `Debug.Print Sheet1.Evaluate("MEDIAN(IFERROR(IF($J:$J <> """",$J:$J), """"))")` works for me.

Comment: Hi guys, it works for me as well finally. BIG THANKS!!

Comment: @ColeLange, guys, a follow-up question: what if I want to avoid negative numbers and zeros in the formula?

Comment: `Debug.Print Sheet1.Evaluate("MEDIAN(IFERROR(IF(($J:$J <> """")*(IF($J:$J >= 0)),$J:$J), """"))")` ?

Comment: Hi @ColeLange, thanks for the update, but this did not work for me. `Error 2015`

Comment: I could not tell you why that is, a little out of my league. Try this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14188010/vba-application-match-error-2015. I'd also suggest googling `Error 2015`.